# Conveying "in a nutshell"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

How can one convey the  idiom 'in a nutshell' (i.e. very briefly, giving only the main points) as

> "What went wrong?"
>
> "In a nutshell, everything."

We can say 'en un mot' but I am wondering if there are other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**. Il me semble qu'il n'existe rien de bien plus lapidaire que « en un mot ». Voici quelques variantes courtes.

- en bref, en résumé, pour résumer, en deux mots, en peu de mots

*Exemple*

- ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wFsYfCyWfwQC&pg=PT294&dq=%22pour+r%C3%A9sumer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfloKemLzsAhUNxIUKHeTGBJwQ6AEwCXoECDMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22pour%20r%C3%A9sumer%22&f=false)) Pour résumer, le programme de formation en service à la clientèle que je propose durerait une journée et comprendrait des exercices interactifs et des instructions pour assurer les contacts directs avec les clients.

**2**. Quatre  expressions  plus longues sont aussi équivalentes mais on utilise peu celles qui sont construites avec le verbe « rentrer » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2Csans+rentrer+dans+les+d%C3%A9tails%2Csans+rentrer+dans+le+d%C3%A9tail%2Csans+entrer+dans+le+d%C3%A9tail%2Csans+entrer+dans+les+d%C3%A9tails&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csans%20rentrer%20dans%20les%20d%C3%A9tails%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20rentrer%20dans%20le%20d%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20entrer%20dans%20le%20d%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20entrer%20dans%20les%20d%C3%A9tails%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csans%20rentrer%20dans%20les%20d%C3%A9tails%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20rentrer%20dans%20le%20d%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20entrer%20dans%20le%20d%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csans%20entrer%20dans%20les%20d%C3%A9tails%3B%2Cc0)).

- sans (r)entrer dans le(s) détail(s)

**3**. Il y a aussi le mot « **bref** » employé tout seul ; cet usage est un [peu familier](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/in%20a%20nutshell) selon certaines opinions, mais personnellement je ne le crois pas; le terme qui serait familier (selon le TLFi) c'est l'équivalent sémantique « **enfin bref** » (voir ci-dessous).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bref)) A.− Empl. comme interj. Enfin, pour le dire en peu de mots!
> ♦ Aujourd'hui ton père tombe chez moi comme une bombe, et me menace du gendarme; bref, un scandale des mille diables. Demain, j'aurais tout le canton sur les bras. Bernanos, Sous le soleil de Satan,1926, p. 79.

- ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_O6KA8j6SaoC&pg=PR5&dq=%22bref%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjs4GTlbzsAhUD6RoKHTdwBacQ6AEwSHoECB8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22bref%22&f=false))  La plupart des Commentaires philosophiques sur Aristote sont terminés . La Somme contre les Gentils est aussi finie . Les grands opuscules , les grandes Questions disputées ont été menés à terme . Bref , saint Thomas a une vision complète ...

**4**. L'adverbe « **enfin** » peut aussi s'utiliser pour dire « in a nutshell ».

> (TLFi]()) 1. [À la fin d'une énumération, d'un développement, pour conclure, abréger, résumer] Synon. bref, en un mot. Enfin, voilà; enfin bref (fam.); enfin, passons.
> ♦ Enfin, vous ne vous êtes pas trompé, c'est le principal, conclut-elle (Huysmans, Oblat,t. 2, 1903, p. 38).

Answer (score 3):

En un mot, tout.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/in-a-nutshell)

Answer (score 3):

The correct translation is either "en somme" or "somme toute" or "en résumé".
"en un mot" is the translation of "in a word".

Source : Ultralingua dictionnary

Answer (score 3):

"En un mot" is often used, but you could hear "en gros", too.

- Qu'est-ce qui s'est mal passé?
- En gros, tout.

See http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/en%20gros/fr-fr/